# Fade In Fade Out effect for Items in asp:Repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fadein, asprepeater, fadeout

I am using an Asp:Repeater to display the Items from the Database. I want to Fade in and Fade out each items in the repeater one after the other. I used the  jQuery Ticker plugin beforebut it did not work.

```
       $(function () {
        $('#fader').fadeIn('slow', function () {
            alert('t');
            fadeItOut();
        });
    });

    function fadeItIn() {
        $('#fader').fadeIn('slow', function () {
            fadeItOut();
        });
    }

    function fadeItOut() {
        $('#fader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            fadeItIn();
        });
    }



});
```

I used the above code and the fader is the id given for the header template of the repeater. What it does is: it displays all the items in the repeater and fades in and out.. What I need is to fade in and out each item one after the other continuously... Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
<ItemTemplate>

    <div id="fader" style=" background-color: lightyellow; overflow: hidden; padding-top:100px; padding-left:100px">
        <div style="display: block; width: 40%; height:100%; float: left; position: relative">
            <h4><%# Eval("title") %></h4>
            <p><%# Item.Description %></p>
        </div>

    </div>

</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Why's there nested `$(function ()` in your code?

Comment: Paste the Repeater code.

Comment: Would you mind posting it as part of the question?

Comment: I can see the code now. But where are you calling the functions fadeItIn and fadeItOut? I can't see it.

Comment: Possibly your id "fader" will be repeated, not allowing the JS function can "capture" it.

Comment: @MelanciaUK : I posted it as a part of my question. Thank you!

Comment: @PiLHA : What can I do to avoid that?

Comment: @bunnie I just made an assumption based on the code, run it see its source code (Ctrl + U) where there is a repeater and confirm that it is returning something like `fader_1`, `fader_2` ... or not.

Comment: Use classes instead of id's and then select the elements. After that you could loop through all elements and use `$(this).fadeIn('slow').fadeOut();`

Comment: @alexP: can you please explain it more or give an example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use class "fader" instead of id and loop through all elements. And avoid inline-styles.

```
 <div class="fader" style="display: none; background-color: lightyellow; overflow: hidden; padding-top:100px; padding-left:100px">
        <div style="display: block; width: 40%; height:100%; float: left; position: relative">
            <h4><%# Eval("title") %></h4>
            <p><%# Item.Description %></p>
        </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var time = 1000;
  (function loop(){
    $('.fader').each(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $self.fadeIn('slow').fadeOut();
        }, time);
        time += 1500;
    });
    loop();
  })();
});
```

Comment: It does throw a runtime error '$' is undefined. I enclosed the jQuery code in <script type = "text/javascript">

Comment: Put `$(document).ready` around your JavaScript and please read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com)

Comment: Yes I did that! but it does fade in and fade out all the items at a time.. I need the items to fade in and out one after the other continuously.

Comment: it does fade in and fade out all the items at a time.. I need the items to fade in and out one after the other continuously

Comment: There is a small problem in the code... For example I have two two rows in my database with values of title and description. With your above code its fading in and out first item twice and then fading in and out second item twice.. What I need is display 1st item and them fade out and then fadein second item and then fade out second item and again fadein first item: like in a loop.. (1.. 2.. 3...1..2..3..)